# How arduino and rails app communicate through wifi?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arduino

I want to make arduino and a Ruby on Rails app communicate through WIFI in a local network.
HOW to do it?
What protocols should I use?HTTP?UDPorTCP?
What arduino should play as?A sever or a client?
In my app.I can control arduino from website when I click a button.
And arduino can send massage from sensor to the sever

Comment: I think this question is really not ruby-on-rails centric. You need to find out what comm protocols your arduino object can handle and then no matter what web app framework you use, you need to tailor communication to that (or those) protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP, TCP is the easiest.

Setup a Ruby on Rails app.

Setup routes on the ROR app.

Program the Arduino to send data to the ROR app routes.

i.e. Get the local IP of the computer with the rails app running, then send requests to that IP and at the open port (Default is 3000). Make sure the firewall is opened on the appropriate ports.

Get more complicated...

Comment: Thanks.So arduino is client.How to control my arduino from website?

Comment: For that, you will have to have the `actions defined in the code before compiling` the code onto the arduino that `listens for data over WiFi` or something and then `performs an action`. *Let me know if you need something else in a new question and mark correct if I helped you.*